# How to resize image with correct propotion in x and y axis using jquery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi please see this https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/x3xb2jwf/15/. Here i can change the size of the image . is it possible to resize the image proportionally with x and y axis ? currently i can enlarge the image to y axis without effecting the x axis . I want to change the image size that is proportional with both x and y axis.

i see this code in documentation

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
  aspectRatio: true
});
```

i used  `aspectRatio: true` ,but nothing changing .

Comment: `aspectRatio` is exactly what you need, and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/x3xb2jwf/12/ ??

Comment: yes  . :) . Please write this as answer for this question

Comment: Thank you friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aspectRatio` of `resizable()` is exactly what you need. I can only presume you're not setting it on the correct element, try this:

```
$(".child2").resizable({
    aspectRatio: true
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x3xb2jwf/12/)

Comment: My mistake.. Thank you .

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342500/jquery-draggable-event-changing-the-css-of-child-element